# Having trouble starting appium server on terminal

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, appium, python-appium

I'm trying to run Appium 1.6.3 on terminal so I can run Appium on iOS simulator. In the past, I was able to start Appium on terminal. Ever since I upgraded the mac OS to 10.12.3, I always get the following error when I tried to run it:

```
-bash: appium: command not found
```

when I tried running appium-doctor, I usually get the following diagnosis:

```
info AppiumDoctor Appium Doctor v.1.3.0
info AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic starting ###
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ The Node.js binary was found at: /usr/local/bin/node
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Node version is 6.9.4
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Xcode is installed at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ Xcode Command Line Tools are NOT installed!
WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ DevToolsSecurity is NOT enabled!
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ The Authorization DB is set up properly.
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Carthage was found at: /usr/local/bin/carthage
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ HOME is set to: /Users/jakerushing
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ ANDROID_HOME is set to: /Users/jakerushing/Library/Android/sdk
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ JAVA_HOME is set to: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ adb exists at: /Users/jakerushing/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ android exists at: /Users/jakerushing/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ emulator exists at: /Users/jakerushing/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Bin directory of $JAVA_HOME is set
info AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic completed, 2 fixes needed. ###
```

When I tried running `xcode-select --install`, I get the error saying that the tools are already installed, and DevToolsSecurity was already enabled. I tried uninstalling XCode command tools and reinstalling and that didn't fix the issue. I am trying to fix this issue for a couple of days and I couldn't find any answers to these questions. I am at a wit's end with this issue.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your log:

```
WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ Xcode Command Line Tools are NOT installed!
WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ DevToolsSecurity is NOT enabled!
```

Work around: Run the command bellow then try to restart Appium doctor again

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
DevToolsSecurity -enable
```

Comment: I tried DevToolsSecurity and it said that it was already enabled

Comment: if the second command from the "workaround" doesn't work, use sudo

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution to my main issue, with appium not running when I type in appium

I found this blog post online and i read the instructions. After that, I was able to run the appium command again!

https://solidgeargroup.com/automated-test-for-ios-with-appium-set-up-the-environment-2

Whoever wrote this saved me a lot of time that I could have wasted looking for a solution. You are a saint.

However, I am still having trouble getting DevToolsSecurity to be detected. When I type in /usr/sbin/DevToolsSecurity -enable, it says that Developer mode is already enabled, and yet when I run appium-doctor or authorize-ios, they both return the following:

```
Error: Command 'DevToolsSecurity' not found. Is it installed?
ERR! AuthorizeIOS     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/jakerushing/.node/lib/node_modules/authorize-ios/node_modules/teen_process/build/lib/teen_process.js:71:14)
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in your terminal:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```